# what cosmic event could teleport a solar system?

Tags: stars, teleportation, cataclysms, galactic

In a project I am mulling over, humanity now inhabits the dense core region of a globular cluster. They did not colonise this cluster; some cosmic event actually teleported the sun, moon and earth (but none of the other planets) into a whole new region of space, thousands of lightyears from the Milky away or even the local group. This is the basis of the project, and while i don’t have to go into detail, I would at least like some kind of vague explanation/excuse to present the reader as to HOW THE HECK THIS HAPPENED.

Any ideas? I know this is a mega-biggie; please feel free to use a liberal dosage of handwavium to make any explanation work.

Comment: There is no real world event that will teleport a solar system. However you can make up whatever event in your world to achieve that. Remember that we’re not a brainstorming site. Asking us to make things up for you is not permitted here.

Comment: The technical term is [alien space bats](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alien_space_bats), usually shortened to ASBs.

Comment: Outside the local group would be *millions* of light years at the least -- M31 is in the Local Group and is 2.5 million light years away; the Milky Way is 100,000 light years across.  Downvote for lack of basic research.

Comment: Brainstorming is not specifically against the rules. See here: https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic
Brainstorming is generally fine within a very specific question, which this is. He needs one mechanic to resolve one very specific issue. Voted to reopen.

Comment: @Jamie Stack Exchange has a prohibition on questions with many equally valid answers. Given that a "liberal dose of handwavium" is on the table this question clearly exceeds that threshold. To quote from the page you linked *"[questions] Must include restrictions/requirements: What will make one answer better than another? If any answer is equally effective your question is not properly constrained."*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Alien Abduction

No known natural phenomenon would cause anything even remotely like this to happen, but it only takes a cursory look at the past few generations of human development to realize that when intelligence gets involved, a lot of unnatural things can done.

When it comes to aliens, there is no known limitation to what something much smarter than us can do; so, if you must handwave something this scientifically outrageous, it's best to go with [Clarke's Third Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clarke%27s_three_laws): "Any sufficiently advanced technology is indistinguishable from magic".

The advantage of aliens doing this over a human action, is that making it work makes a lot more since.  For humans to do something like this on purpose, means humans have likely spent years building and experimenting with the technology; so, when it does happen, it's no surprise to anyone, and we are not spending the resources going anywhere that would not already be well explored and advantageous to us.  To handwave this as an accident means something went very wrong, and when things go wrong at this scale, the likelihood of living things coming out the other side goes way down.

This just leaves something going very right... but not from the human perspective.

Answer (score 0):

## Accidental Hypospace Trip

Hypospace is defined as any space with less than 3 spatial and 1 temporal dimension.

Humans were testing the ability to travel FTL with a Hypodrive™, and things went really wrong. The containment field didn’t work, and now the whole solar system (up to Jupiter and the asteroid belt) got chucked into the dense core of your globular cluster.

Pros:

- Hypospace isn’t entirely fictional
- minimal hand waving

Cons:

- requires a bit more of the solar system to fly with you

Comment: Interesting! Could you provide a link to an article on Hypospace so I can learn more?

Comment: @user98816, Hypo means less, and we can picture 2 dimensional (circles, square), 1 dimensional objects (lines), and 0 dimensional objects (points).